# How to set the location of a JRadioButton?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jradiobutton

I want to organize my buttons in a 3x3 box. Which layout should I use and how do I use it?

Answer (score 2):

[`GridLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)

[image]

[`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

[image]

Check out [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

[How to use GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html). What to use and how.

Answer (score 0):

I'd  thought this small piece of code might help u out......I did it in net beans but I have commented on the important part for u....and if u can be more specific about "organizing", I can help u out...but AFAIK..if you mean organizing as getting them in a group...then u know its very easy to group them and u can also use a for loop to label all the buttons... ;) ...if there is anything else let me know...I havent been concerned much about the size of the layout..so output layout must be small but Im sure u can set its size ;) cheers !

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GridLayoutJRB {
public final static boolean RIGHT_TO_LEFT = false;

public static void addComponentsToPane(Container contentPane) {
    if (RIGHT_TO_LEFT) {    // blah ! blah ! blah !
        contentPane.setComponentOrientation(
            ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
    }
//        3  rows and 3 columns..this is what you require here .. :)
    contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

    contentPane.add(new JRadioButton("1"));
    contentPane.add(new JRadioButton("2"));
    contentPane.add(new JRadioButton("3"));
    contentPane.add(new JRadioButton("4"));
    contentPane.add(new JRadioButton("5"));
    contentPane.add(new JRadioButton("6"));
    contentPane.add(new JRadioButton("7"));
    contentPane.add(new JRadioButton("8"));
    contentPane.add(new JRadioButton("9"));
}
//again blah blah blah !
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridLayout With JRadio Buttons");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Set up the content pane and components in GridLayout
    addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: and yeah its the GridLayout :D